# Spring Cloud Stream - route to multiple dynamic destinations at runtime

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream

I have a use-case where I need to produce to multiple Kafka topics/destinations determined at runtime. I tried to combine [Functions with multiple input and output arguments](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_functions_with_multiple_input_and_output_arguments) by using a returning `Flux<Message<T>>` from a functional bean of type `Function` with setting the header `spring.cloud.stream.sendto.destination` for each `Message` as described [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_spring_cloud_stream_sendto_destination). I came up with the following implementation:

```
@Bean
public Function<Person, Flux<Message<Person>>> route() {
    return person -> Flux.fromIterable(Stream.of(person.getEvents())
            .map(e -> MessageBuilder.withPayload(person)
                    .setHeader("spring.cloud.stream.sendto.destination", e).build())
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

and I have also this in my config:

```
spring.cloud.stream.dynamic-destinations=
```

This is my `Person`:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Person {
    private String[] events;
    private String name;
}
```

`events` contains the list of Kafka topic names.

However, it doesn't work. What am I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution that works uses `BinderAwareChannelResolver`. However, it's deprecated in favor if providing `spring.cloud.stream.sendto.destination` property in 3.0.

```
@Autowired
private BinderAwareChannelResolver binderAwareChannelResolver;

@Bean
public Consumer<Person> route() {
return person ->
        Stream.of(person.getEvents())
                .forEach(e -> binderAwareChannelResolver.resolveDestination(e)
                        .send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(person).build()));
}
```

I don't like this solution because it combines the function-based programming model with the "legacy-style" programming model. If anyone has a better solution, please feel free to comment/answer.

Answer (score 5):

`spring.cloud.stream.sendto.destination` uses `BinderAwareChannelResolver` internally which is deprecated in favor of `StreamBridge`. I think you can rewrite your code as below. I haven't tested it, but here is the template:

```
@Autowired StreamBridge streamBridge;

@Bean
public Consumer<Person> route() {
    return person -> streamBridge.send(person.getName(), person);
}
```

Behind the scenes, Spring Cloud Stream will create a binding for `Person` dynamically.

If you know your destinations in advance at deployment time, you can also set them through configuration. For e.g. `spring.cloud.stream.source` as `foo;bar..;...`. Then the framework creates output bindings in the form of `foo-out-0`, `bar-out-0` etc. Then you need to set destinations - `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.foo-out-0.destination=foo`. But since your use case is strictly about dynamic destinations, you can't go with this approach, rather try using what I suggested above.